# Openlayers drag feature not working in Google Chrome

Tags: openlayers

Openlayers drag feature is not working in Google Chrome. But it works fine in Opera, Firefox and IE.

You can find an example of Openlayers Drag Feature:

http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/drag-feature.html

Please guide me how the Openlayers drag feature works in Google Chrome. Thanks.

Comment: Works for me using Chrome Version 27.0.1453.94 m, which version of Openlayers are you using and which version of Chrome ?

Comment: Openlayers version Release 2.13 dev and Chrome Version 27.0.1453.94 m. @Chistope Roussy

Comment: At this time 2.12 is the stable version, maybe it got broken in 2.13

Comment: I faced with problem too. Have you got solution?